# How to use a key of one interface dynamically in another in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to dynamically generate a type based on the key(s) of an existing type.

```js
interface A {
    X: number
}

type S = keyof A // correct "X"
type V = A[S] // correct: number

type B = {
    [S]: A[S] // Error: A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an
              // expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

}
```

What is the correct way to generate a type with dynamic properties based on the key of another type?

Comment: You're trying to create interface `B` which will be exactly the same as `A`? What is the point of that?

Comment: @JuanMendes my actual use case is a bit more complicated... it ended up like `{[K in keyof T]: {get(this: {[S in typeof key]: number}): T[K]}}`

I just tried to simplify to the part I was having trouble with so the question was concise and answerable.

Comment: Now I want to know what that is doing  Looks gnarly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close. All you need to change is `[S]: A[S]` to `[k in S]: A[k]`.

```
interface A {
    X: number
    Y: string;
}

type S = keyof A;

type B = {
    [k in S]: A[k];
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-IAaAXMiAK4C2ARtLgcgJqkDOYUoA5gNy4C+uXGACeABxQBlZAF5kAawjCA9jDS8cQsSgBCMzPQIBtOclDIJAXVKpjF9XyA)

Comment: [Documentation for Mapped Types in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types) has almost this exact same code for a `Partial` implementation. I'm really curious as to how the OP wants to use it since this doesn't really achieve anything, just a copy of the original type?

Comment: @JuanMendes I assume this is part of a larger type. Maybe `B` consists of props from many other interfaces, and has props of its own. While there are more elegant ways of constructing such a type, it may not be obvious to new typescript users.

Comment: What you just described is just `extends`, isn't it? 

Comment: @JuanMendes yupp :P

Comment: Thanks I ran into some confusion about the interactions between `keyof`, `typeof` and `in` and this helped me out!